# Nelly rebelliously cheers Italian food

Tags: cryptic-clues, crosswords

P?S??

> Now I'm thinking it has to be either PESTO or PASTA but I really can't see how it works with the clue. I thought rebelliously was an anagram indicator but the P and S are definitely correct...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is:

> **PASTA** = **SAP<** + **TA**
>
>  A "nelly" is a silly person or a **SAP** and rebelliously is a reversal indicator in a down clue; think of a rebellion as an uprising. (It could also be an anagram indicator, but that would mean an indirect anagram here, which is generally frowned upon.) "Cheers!" means thanks or just **TA**.

Comment: Thanks M Oehm, that makes sense!